# How to implement GWT PlaceHistoryMapper with custom tokens?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-places

I'd like my small GWT app to have all of the following "bookmarkable" `Place`s:

```
http://www.mywebapp.com                 -->     "home page"
http://www.mywebapp.com/login           -->     login screen
http://www.mywebapp.com/main            -->     main menu, after logged in
http://www.mywebapp.com/start           -->     start of a transactional process
http://www.mywebapp.com/complete        -->     end of transactional process (receipt)
```

So I went ahead and created 5 `Place` subclasses, all of which take the following form:

```
public class LoginPlace extends Place {
    // Intentionally left void because I'm not sure
    // what to implement here...
}
```

And have corresponding tokenizers:

```
public class LoginPlaceTokenizer extends PlaceTokenizer<LoginPlace> {
    @Override
    public LoginPlace getPlace(String token) {
        // ???
    }

    @Override
    public String getToken(LoginPlace place) {
        // ???
    }
}
```

I'm trying to implement a `PlaceHistoryMapper` for my app:

```
@WithTokenizers({
    HomePlaceTokenizer.class,
    LoginPlaceTokenizer.class,
    MainMenuPlaceTokenizer.class
    // etc.
})
public class MyWebAppPlaceHistoryMapper implements PlaceHistoryMapper {
    @Override
    public Place getPlace(String token) {
        // ???
    }

    @Override
    public String getToken(Place place) {
        // ???
    }
}
```

The companion `getPlace`/`getToken` methods in the `PlaceTokenizer<T>` subclasses and in `MyWebAppPlaceHistoryMapper` seem to be doing the same thing. **Are they?** If so, do I just use the same code inside both of them? If they are not the same, how are they different, and how should I be implementing them?

Keep in mind the URL tokens that I want as the bookmarkable places in the app - I don't want to use GWT's default `someDisplay:SomePlace` tokens. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either you use an interface annotated with `@WithTokenizers` and let GWT generate the implementation from a `GWT.create(MyWebAppPlaceHistoryMapper.class)`, or you implement the `PlaceHistoryMapper` interface "by hand" and you don't need `PlaceTokenizer`s.

With `GWT.create()`, GWT will implement the `getPlace` and `getToken` methods to **dispatch** to the appropriate `PlaceTokenizer` depending on the prefix of the token (using a `if…else` cascade with `prefix.equals(...)`, based on the `@Prefix` annotations on the `PlaceTokenizer`s) or the type of the `Place` (using a `if…else` cascade with `instanceof`, based on the generic type of the `PlaceTokenizer`s).

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Broyer (+1) - that makes sense. As for customizing the tokens, **how would I implement the `getToken(Place place)` method so that a token of `/login` would be a token for a `LoginPlace` that bookmarks to `http://www.mywebapp.com/login`?** Thanks again!

Comment: `if (place instanceof LoginPlace) { return "login"; }`, and similarly for `getPlace`: `if ("login".equals(token)) { return new LoginPlace(); }`. But having `http://www.mywebapp.com/login` requires using the HTML5 `pushState` and `popstate` and having your server prepared to send the same page for many URLs; see https://gist.github.com/1883821

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out. I'll refrain for asking deeper questions about HTML5 pushState/popState and your `Html5Historian` because they wouldn't be related to this question, but: (1) will using this limit my web app's audience to modern browsers that are HTML5-compliant? And (2) Is there any documentation on why this requires HTML5 pushState/popState? I guess I'm just surprised that this is not a normal way ok bookmarking different places in GWT. As always, thanks!